# Not able to deploy custom web template at farm scope

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, web-template, farm

I have developed a custom Web Template based on "BDR#0" in SP 2013. It works perfect and I can deploy it using Site scope feature. The web template is developed by adding a Module in VS 2012 which includes Elements.xml and ONET.xml files as seen below:

[image]

I want to deploy web Template at Farm scope, But When I deploy using Farm scope feature, it gives following error:

Project Item "DCWebTemplate" cannot be deployed through a Feature with Farm scope.
Whats wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because your DCWebTemplate is a module.

You can't use a module to deploy to farm. If you check your spi-file you can see the attribute SupportedDeploymentScopes is only web and site.

```
<ProjectItem Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Module" SupportedTrustLevels="All" SupportedDeploymentScopes="Web, Site" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2010/SharePointTools/SharePointProjectItemModel">
```

Instead you should use a Empty Element item. Below is the spi for that type.

```
<ProjectItem Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.GenericElement" DefaultFile="Elements.xml" SupportedTrustLevels="All" SupportedDeploymentScopes="Web, Site, WebApplication, Farm, Package" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2010/SharePointTools/SharePointProjectItemModel">
```

Answer (score 3):

WebTemplate isn't allowed in Farm scoped features. See [Elements by Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454835%28v=office.14%29.aspx) even though it's for SP2010 it can be used as a guideline for SP2013.

The best you can do is WebApplications scope